# Blazor Server JWT error: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm struggling for days to make the JWT authentication working in my .NET 6.0 **Blazor Server** app!
I'm getting this error message:

*InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.*

I Created this class:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
    private readonly HttpClient _http;

    public CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorage, HttpClient http)
    {
        _localStorage = localStorage;
        _http = http;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        string token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("token"); //The exception is thrown at this line

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        
        ...

        return state;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        ...
    }

    private static byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

My Program.cs is the default one, I just added those services:

```
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
    builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
```

The exception is thrown at this line: `string token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("token");`
I'm trying to use Blazored.LocalStorage for the local storage, but I also tried with ProtectedLocalStorage and got the same error!

Can you please help me on how to fix this exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438796/javascript-interop-error-when-calling-javascript-from-oninitializedasync-blazor

Comment: @stuartd Not reall,y because I'm not calling GetAuthenticationStateAsync(), it's being called automatically by the CascadingAuthenticationState!

Comment: Ok but your exception message is telling you what you need to do - _”When prerendering is enabled, **JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync event**_” and the answer to that question has an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blazor Server is rendered 2 times, once at server and once at client. When it is rendered in the server, there is no local storage there. Because of that, you need an empty try catch to ignore the error that no local storage.

```
try
{
    string token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("token"); //The exception is thrown at this line
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
}
```

Comment: What type of state should you return if the ```InvalidOperationException``` is hit since ```GetAuthenticationStateAsync``` always expects a state back?